# AppStore - Give paid app for free when user entering a code

Tags: xcode, xcode5, app-store

I have a paid and a free version of a game in the AppStore. Now a magazin wants to write about the game. They want to give the reader of the magazin the fullversion for free. In the freeversion it is only possible to play one level. The idea was to put a textfield in the freeversion where the reader can put in the code. And then the freeversion transform to fullversion so that the player can play all levels.

The problem is in the freeversion is no GameCenter and i also want that all the player are saved in the fullversion and not in the freeversion.

Is there a way to give a paid app for free when the user put somewhere a code?

Answer (score 1):

How about promocodes.

You can extract 100 promocodes for any of your app. You can request the promocodes in itunesconnect

You can give some 10 to 20 promo code to these magazine and the users who reads the magazine first and enters the promocode in appstore for your app they can download the app for free.

Let free version be separate and no need for any changes in free version.

More about [promo codes here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!! But promocodes is not the right way for me! i used promocodes to prenset the game. But the magazin wants a code for every reader!! so the 100 promocodes are not enough. Do you have an other idea??

Comment: Other solution would be. You should have a single app which is by default free. But you can use Inapp purchases/some code to unlock the full version. You have to define a logic/algorithm that these kind of codes should be accepted and you should be able to unlock the features based on the code/inapp purchase

Comment: Thanks!! The problem is that the app is already in the appstore!! it is not possible to include inapppurchase!! i need another way!! do you have an other idea?? thanks